# I am new to angular and I don't know how to resolve TS(2322) error?

Tags: angular, typescript, visual-studio-code, compiler-errors

```
Main Code:

export class TodosComponent implements OnInit{
  todos!: Todo[]; 
  localItem: string;
  constructor(){
    const item = localStorage.getItem("todos");
    this.localItem = item;
    if(this.localItem == null){
      this.todos = [];
    }
    else{
      console.log(this.todos);
      this.todos = JSON.parse("localItem");
    }
  }
```

This is what I got after compilation
ERROR
src/app/MyComponents/todos/todos.component.ts:14:5 - error TS2322: Type 'string | null' is not assignable to type 'string'.
Type 'null' is not assignable to type 'string'.

14     this.localItem =`your text` item;

I tried by adding,
const localItem: string | null = getValueFromSomewhere();
but it didn't worked

Comment: [tag:angular] **is not the same as** [tag:angularjs].  it's unlikely that this code belongs to [tag:angularjs].

Answer (score 0):

Reading Items from the localStorage can potential return null (if the key does not exist in the localStorage) therefore `localStorage.getItem("todos")` could either return a string or null. In your case, you are assigning it to `this.localItem` which based on your time will always be a string. So you either adjust the type of `this.localItem` to be `string | null` or you perform an accurate null check for item first, for example like this:

```
export class TodosComponent implements OnInit{
  todos!: Todo[]; 
  localItem: string;
  constructor(){
    const item = localStorage.getItem("todos");
    if(item == null){
      this.todos = [];
    }
    else{
    this.localItem = item;
      console.log(this.todos);
      this.todos = JSON.parse("localItem");
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in [Wortmann's Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76714785/14413007).

There are multiple ways to handle your case.

Some of them are :

1. Changing type of localItem to string|null.

```js
export class TodosComponent implements OnInit{
  todos!: Todo[]; 
  localItem: string|null;
  constructor(){
    this.localItem = localStorage.getItem("todos");
    if(this.localItem == null){
      this.todos = [];
    }
    else{
      console.log(this.todos);
      this.todos = JSON.parse("localItem");
    }
  }
```

2. using `??` operator.

```js
export class TodosComponent implements OnInit{
  todos!: Todo[]; 
  localItem: string;
  constructor(){
    this.localItem = localStorage.getItem("todos") ?? "";
    if(this.localItem == ""){
      this.todos = [];
    }
    else{
      console.log(this.todos);
      this.todos = JSON.parse("localItem");
    }
  }
```